# Phones Pro: Why are rollover calls classified as missed?

Tags: phone-call

If CSR1 is already on a call and another call comes in, they are unable to answer the new call and it rolls over to CSR2. If CSR2 answers the call, the call is not missed. Why does CSR1 receive a missed call metric for that call if:

1. They were on another call and physically unable to answer
2. The call was answered by someone else so it wasn't missed

Is it expected behavior to penalize CSR1 for already being on a call?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phones Pro, so I can't give you a proper answer, but thinking from an industry perspective: "Missed calls" is just a metric. What you do with that metric is up to your business. CSR1 is not being "penalized" here - they just missed a call, and the reason they did, as you said, is because they were "physically unable to answer". Just to make it clear, here's another wording for it: The software is just showing to you what happened - CSR1 missed a call, CSR2 took it. What you do with this information is up to you.

Comment: Having said all that - I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to software development - it's about how a specific consumer-facing piece of software works.